# EF4 definition not updating

Tags: git, entity-framework-4, edmx, appharbor

I have an EDMX file that I generally populate using "Update Model from Database".

Recently, I changed one field in the database from varchar(2) to varchar(15).

The EDMX was updated, and looking through the XML file, I see that varchar(15) is in all the right places.  The web application is working fine in development.

When published to the server (AppHarbor using git), the code fails when updating that field with "EntityValidationErrors" showing "The field TallyStatus must be a string or array type with a maximum length of 2".

The production database is updated with the varchar(15) size.  I've completely recreated the EDMX file and republished, and still have the problem.

What else can I do? Or check?

Answer (score 0):

In the EDMX designer, select that field in your entity and then check the properties for a setting called "Max Length". Ensure that this value is 15.

Comment: Thanks for the thought... it is definitely at 15.